# Удалить данные из params

Tags: forms, post, request, ruby-on-rails

Выполняется post-запрос в контроллере users_controller на изменение данных в объекте с моделью user, в post из edit.html.erb передаются параметры. Как удалить из params параметр `:password` и `:password_confirmation`, если поля на форме пустые?

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в доку по [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html) посмотреть никак?

```
params.delete[:password] unless params[:password].present?
params.delete[:password_confirmation] unless params[:password_confirmation].present?
```

Comment: Вообщето `params` не является `Hash`. Но работает как написали.

Comment: Так я уже по-всякому пытаюсь, так тоже не хочет, делает пароль пустой...